# Awaiting Referee Selection in 11 weeks

Tags: publications

Recently, I have submitted a mathematical paper to a journal published by Taylor & Francis. After some days, the status of the paper was changed from Submitted to Journal to AWAITING REFEREE SELECTION. Up to now,  11 weeks passed but the status is still AWAITING REFEREE SELECTION. I have contacted to Editorial Office several but the result is not changed. How should we respond to them in this case?

Comment: _I have contacted to Editorial Office several but the result is not changed_ – did anything happen after you contacting them? For example, did you get a reply?

Comment: Is this the same paper submitted over 2 years ago or another slow one?  I would think to yank the paper.  Figure out which journals have faster processing.

Comment: You contacted them several times in 11 weeks?  In mathematics, my rule was do not contact the journal until at least 6 months.

Comment: @GEdgar I don't think so. If the time from submission to the first decision is 6 months (25 weeks) then that is too good. But 11 weeks for choosing a reviewer is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

There is little you can do, actually, and eleven weeks doesn't sound excessive. That is especially true if the number of potential reviewers is small, as for an esoteric paper. But kicking them more isn't going to get them to move any faster, and might make them move slower if they get upset. Adding to their workload by needing to respond to you doesn't speed them up, of course.

Some academics have a different schedule at the end of a year and the first of the new year, so that might account for the delay.

But they really have no incentive to slow it down and every incentive to make it work. If you have no trust in them, withdraw the paper and submit it elsewhere, knowing that the clock restarts if you you do that.

There is also, possibly, some time delay in changing the status even after reviewers have been found.

Comment: The OP didn't give a field, but in those that I'm familiar with, 11 weeks to not even invite reviewers is excessive. Also, with modern editorial management systems, there should be no time delay in changing the status once reviewers have been invited; it's instant.

Comment: @Allure, there is know information here about "invitations". They may have been made, several times, in fact.